# Execute Package Task by Package Name for Sql Server Stored Packages

Tags: ssis

I've seen where people execute different packages by name on the file system by changing the file system connection information via a variable.  I need to execute different packages on Sql Server.  Has anyone seen a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the packages to sql agent and then executing the bia msdb.dbo.sp_start_job [agent job name]